# Nested JSON from datatable and IList

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two variables

> `Datatable listOfObject`

which is producing JSON like below

```
"listofObject" : [
{
   "Obj1": "Some String Value",
   "Obj2": "Some Date Value",
   "Obj3": "Some Int Value",
   "Obj4": "Some Date Value",
....
}
]
```

and another object

> `IList<Class> ObjectInfo`

which is producing JSON like below

```
"ObjectInfo" : [
  {
     "name" : "Obj1",
     "Style" : "Style Name",
     "Data Type" : "String"
  },
  {
     "name" : "Obj2",
     "Style" : "Style Name",
     "Data Type" : "Date"
  },
  {
     "name" : "Obj3",
     "Style" : "Style Name",
     "Data Type" : "Int"
  },
.....
]
```

how can I combine them to have a JSON structure Like below

```
"finalStructure" :[
  "Obj1": {
         "Style" : "Style Name",
         "Data Type" : "String"
          },
  "Obj2": {
         "Style" : "Style Name",
         "Data Type" : "Date"
          },
  "Obj3": {
         "Style" : "Style Name",
         "Data Type" : "Int"
          },
....
]
```

Comment: You can create a class which mocking intended structure containing data from both instances, unfortunately at this moment you're not showing your current attempt to achieve that.

Comment: It looks to me like you are not combining them at all; your final JSON structure only includes data from the `ObjectInfo` list.  Are the values from the `DataTable` supposed to be in there somewhere?  Also, the final structure you are asking for is invalid JSON; key-value pairs cannot appear directly inside of an array.  Did you mean for those square brackets `[]` to be curly braces `{}`?

Comment: @BrianRogers yeah, I can only make it work if they are curly braces. (without using any classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a datatable, you have an `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>`, so what you want to do is first create a lookup, then you can safely project your results:

```
var items = listOfObjects.FromJson<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>>();

var info = objectInfo.FromJson<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>>()
    .ToLookup(it => it.Single(k => k.Key == "name").Value, it => it.Where(k => k.Key != "name"));

var restructured = items
    .SelectMany(it => it.Keys)
    .GroupBy(it => it)
    .Select(it => new
    {
        Key = it.Key,
        Value = info[it.Key].SelectMany(fo => fo).ToDictionary(fo => fo.Key, fo => fo.Value)
    })
    .ToDictionary(it => it.Key, it => it.Value);

// extension method with NewtonSoft.JSON.net
public static T FromJson<T>(this string json)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jr);
        return result;
    }
}
```